# using bdwgc, libgc, how to test if it's working

Tags: c++, garbage-collection, libvlc

I wrote a long on C++ program that's works fine, in most cases and machines.

It uses:

- Qt5 version 5.5.1
- (vlc) libvlc 2.2.7
- running on Ubuntu 16.04,
- linux image 4.4.0-174-generic

But testing it on another machine, when main loop pass almost 30 iterations (every iteration take 3 minutes approx.) the system gets unstable and slow.

I've made a test with **valgrind**. I can read the summary as follows.

```
> ==16327== LEAK SUMMARY:
> ==16327==    definitely lost: 1,240 bytes in 10 blocks
> ==16327==    indirectly lost: 11,373 bytes in 354 blocks
> ==16327==      possibly lost: 13,741,198 bytes in 3,961 blocks
> ==16327==    still reachable: 515,970,584 bytes in 138,649 blocks
> ==16327==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
> ==16327==                         length64           : 138,624 bytes in 294 blocks
> ==16327==                         newarray           : 5,466 bytes in 189 blocks
> ==16327==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==16327== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
> ==16327== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
> ==16327== 
> ==16327== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
> ==16327== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
> ==16327== ERROR SUMMARY: 10002390 errors from 2404 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

The leaks appears with vlc object creation.

```
vlc_main->vlcMedia_Player = libvlc_media_player_new(vlc_main->vlcInstance);  // LEAK
libvlc_media_t *vlcMedia = libvlc_media_new_path(vlc_main->vlcInstance, _current_theme.theme_path.toUtf8().constData()); // LEAK
libvlc_media_player_set_media(vlc_main->vlcMedia_Player, vlcMedia);
libvlc_media_release(vlcMedia);
```

That's driving me crazy because I have not found how to deal with libvlc code.

So, I've compiled with bdwgc Boehm-Demers-Weiser C/C++ Garbage Collector.

After the compilation Valgrind still showing me the leak Summary.

I've adjusted:

```
echo GC_FIND_LEAK=1
```

and others.

But I still unsure if my program is garbage collecting.

Comment: Have you tried calling [libvlc_media_player_release()](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__media__player.html#ga210a0f60ad0a2a7ac0460269b5ac2b34) on `vlc_main->vlcMedia_Player`?

Comment: @Alan Birtles    :(  I did it.  but  `code`libvlc_media_player_release(vlc_main->vlcMedia_Player);`code`  destroy the execution.  I need vlc_main->vlcMedia_Player alive to handle it.

Comment: use latest libvlc version, do not use libvlc 2.x

Comment: @mtz  I need to run it on Ubuntu 16.04, I have not found a ppa with a modern vlc. I have compiled vlc, but it runs with many weirds verbose outputs.

Comment: Use `--quiet` then. But libvlc 2 is not a good option